# read -N and IFS

Tags: bash, ifs

According to "read -N" description in manual page:

*-N nchars  return only after reading exactly NCHARS characters, unless EOF is encountered or read times out, ignoring any delimiter*

However, in answer to following command:

```
$ echo 'a b' | while read -N1 c; do echo ">>>$c<<<"; done
>>>a<<<
>>><<<
>>>b<<<
>>><<<
```

both, space and newline have been translated into empty string, while in the command:

```
$ echo 'a b' | while IFS= read -N1 c; do echo ">>>$c<<<"; done
>>>a<<<
>>> <<<
>>>b<<<
>>>
<<<
```

space and newline have been stored correctly in the variable.

So, it seems delimiters still has some processing in "read" or "while" command, that I do not understand.

We could compare these results with the ones using "read -n", that manual described as:

*-n nchars  return after reading NCHARS characters rather than waiting for a newline, but honor a delimiter if fewer than NCHARS    characters are read before the delimiter*

```
$ echo 'a b' | while read -n1 c; do echo ">>>$c<<<"; done
>>>a<<<
>>><<<
>>>b<<<
>>><<<

$ echo 'a b' | while IFS= read -n1 c; do echo ">>>$c<<<"; done
>>>a<<<
>>> <<<
>>>b<<<
>>><<<
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `hexdump` allows us to see exactly the characters making up the output, so it may be helpful to slightly change your queries:

(1) With normal IFS and using -N option

```
$ (echo 'a b' | while read -N1 c; do c="$c<"; echo -n "$c"; done | hexdump -C)
00000000  61 3c 3c 62 3c 3c                                 |a<<b<<|
00000006
```

In this first case, the read builtin for both `0x0a` and the space character returns the empty string, as characters are in the default IFS and characters in the IFS are ignored in the output for the reason explained in cdarke's answer.

(2) With empty IFS and -N option

```
$ (IFS=""; echo 'a b' | while read -N1 c; do c="$c<"; echo -n "$c"; done | hexdump -C)
00000000  61 3c 20 3c 62 3c 0a 3c                              |a< <b<.<|
00000008
```

In this case, the read builtin will match each of the four characters that the echo command outputs, and both `0x0a` and a space are seen in the output, because with an empty IFS the characters read can be assigned to the local variable `c`.

(3) With normal IFS and -n option

```
$ (echo 'a b' | while read -n1 c; do c="$c<"; echo -n "$c"; done | hexdump -C)
00000000  61 3c 3c 62 3c 3c                                 |a<<b<<|
00000006
```

This gives just the same output as case (1), although the semantics are a bit different: the read builtin for both `0x0a` and the space character return the empty string, as (i) both of these characters are in the default IFS and (ii) the -n option to the read builtin in any case does not pass on the trailing `0x0a` character

(4) With empty IFS and -n option

```
$ (IFS=""; echo 'a b' | while read -n1 c; do c="$c<"; echo -n "$c"; done | hexdump -C)
00000000  61 3c 20 3c 62 3c 3c                              |a< <b<<|
00000007
```

Here we observe a difference between the -n and -N options to read: with the -n option, the newline is treated specially by the read builtin and dropped, hence the exclusion of `0x0a` from IFS doesn't have an opportunity to allow it to be passed to the local variable `c`.

Comment: Excellent explanation, but still one open point, the newline in case (4), that is handled in a different way than space, even when none belongs to IFS. That is, I think in case (3) we can not say "0x0a and the space character return the empty string, as both of these characters are in the default IFS".

Comment: @pasabaporaqui - You are quite right: the semantics of the -n switch means it is redundant that `0x0a` is in the IFS.  I've changed the discussion to make this redundancy clear.

Comment: Perfect, just an editorial comment in case (2):  "IFS unset" should be " IFS empty".

Answer (score 4):

This is [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html) behaviour.  When assigning to a variable, IFS characters should be stripped:  *the results shall be split into fields as in the shell for the results of parameter expansion* (of course, -n and -N are not POSIX).

This is born-out by the `read` source code comments:

```
/* This code implements the Posix.2 spec for splitting the words
     read and assigning them to variables. */
  orig_input_string = input_string;

  /* Remove IFS white space at the beginning of the input string.  If
     $IFS is null, no field splitting is performed. */
```

Comment: Very interesting. Only the conversion of newline to empty string in case of "while IFS= read -n1 c" seems difficult to match with these descriptions. I've expected or "end of loop" and nothing printed or a newline assignment. In fact, this case is the only one difference found between -n1 and -N1 tests.

Comment: A newline is part of the default `IFS` setting, in other words it is a delimiter.  I don't see any inconsistency.

Comment: yes, but default IFS (unset IFS) is not the same than empty IFS, that is the one used in this set. Moreover, space is also in the default delimiter set, and in this test is handled in a different way.

Comment: Default IFS is not an unset IFS.  The default is set to `' \r\n'`.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, while using option `-N`, the behavior of `read` is different when

- *Reading* a delimiter as input
- *Assigning* that delimiter to a variable

When it's reading a character, a delimiter treats as same as a non-delimiter and `read` will count them. But, when `read` is assigning the delimiter, it considers that if the read input is a delimiter or not, if it's a delimiter it assigns a null to the corresponding variable.

So, `IFS=` will change the behavior of assigning a white-space to a variable and causes a space to be assigned to `c` rather than a null.

Answer (score 1):

`read` cannot decide if a character is a delimiter (to ignore it) until it has already read the character, and `read` must assign *some* value to `c`, even if that value is the empty string. When a delimiter is read and subsequently discarded, the value of `c` must be set to *something*, so it is assigned the empty string.

This is consistent with `read` used without the `-n/-N` options; delimiters are only discarded *after* they are read and if they aren't necessary to set the value of the provided parameter(s). The simplest case is when you don't provide any arguments to `read`:

```
$ read <<< " a b c "
$ echo ">>>$REPLY<<<"
>>> a b c <<<
```

With a single explicit argument, leading and trailing delimiters are stripped:

```
$ read line <<< " a b c "
$ echo ">>>$line<<<"
>>>a b c<<<
```

With *two* arguments, the first delimiter is ignored once it has been read. The second is retained, because the string only needs to be split into two words to fill the provided parameters.

```
$ read field1 field2 <<< " a b c """
$ echo ">>>$field1<<<"
>>>a<<<
$ echo ">>>$field2<<<"
>>>b c<<<
```